# How to stop moving Divs leaving the length of the document? Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have couple of divs that have an event listener when the document is scrolling and it takes the current Y position of the scroll and times is by a little to move the divs. Like so:

```
ypos = window.pageYOffset;
contactLinks.style.top = ypos * 3.5 + 'px';
```

This means that the div will continue going if I keep scrolling.

How can I try to stop the div from going out of the `innerHeight`?

I tried to initially compare the div `contactLinks.style.top` to the `innerHeight` but it kept going to the else block.

This is the code:

```
let clientHeight = window.innerHeight;
document.addEventListener('scroll', parallex);

function parallex() {
    if (contactLinks.style.top >= clientHeight) {
        contactLinks.style.top = clientHeight + 'px';
    } else {
        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        contactLinks.style.top = ypos * 3.5 + 'px';
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
function parallex() {
    if (ypos >= clientHeight) {
        contactLinks.style.top = clientHeight + 'px';
    } else {
        ypos = window.pageYOffset;
        contactLinks.style.top = ypos * 3.5 + 'px';
    }
}
```

I tried to search it but possibly I did not word it well and didn't have much luck!

Comment: can you provide a code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

contactLinks.style.top is a string (e.g. "700px"), while window.innerHeight is a number (e.g. 700). Comparing them will give unexpected result.

You can use offsetTop:

```
if (contactLinks.offsetTop >= clientHeight) {
    contactLinks.style.top = clientHeight + 'px';
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In SO instead of "thanks" type of comments, use "accept answer" and "upvote" options.